# TemporaryUrl Images not working in production and returning 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have encountered this problem and I am not able to find a solution, since in my previous projects it has not given me any type of problem.

**When using Livewire's temporaryUrl() method to display the image preview, it returns a 401 Authorized on the image and is not able to display it.**

**The strange thing about all this is that images with .gif or .webp format are able to display them, so I no longer know where the problem is.**

**The extensions are activated in the preview_mimes of the livewire config, so it doesn't make much sense.
The APP_URL is correct, so this cannot be a reason for the error.**

Does anyone have an idea?

**Livewire config**

`<?php

return [

```
/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Namespace
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value sets the root class namespace for Livewire component classes in
| your application. This value will change where component auto-discovery
| finds components. It's also referenced by the file creation commands.
|
*/

'class_namespace' => 'App\\Livewire',

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| View Path
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value is used to specify where Livewire component Blade templates are
| stored when running file creation commands like `artisan make:livewire`.
| It is also used if you choose to omit a component's render() method.
|
*/

'view_path' => resource_path('views/livewire'),

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Layout
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| The view that will be used as the layout when rendering a single component
| as an entire page via `Route::get('/post/create', CreatePost::class);`.
| In this case, the view returned by CreatePost will render into $slot.
|
*/

'layout' => 'components.layouts.app',

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Lazy Loading Placeholder
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Livewire allows you to lazy load components that would otherwise slow down
| the initial page load. Every component can have a custom placeholder or
| you can define the default placeholder view for all components below.
|
*/

'lazy_placeholder' => null,

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Temporary File Uploads
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Livewire handles file uploads by storing uploads in a temporary directory
| before the file is stored permanently. All file uploads are directed to
| a global endpoint for temporary storage. You may configure this below:
|
*/

'temporary_file_upload' => [
    'disk' => null,        // Example: 'local', 's3'              | Default: 'default'
    'rules' => null,       // Example: ['file', 'mimes:png,jpg']  | Default: ['required', 'file', 'max:12288'] (12MB)
    'directory' => null,   // Example: 'tmp'                      | Default: 'livewire-tmp'
    'middleware' => null,  // Example: 'throttle:5,1'             | Default: 'throttle:60,1'
    'preview_mimes' => [   // Supported file types for temporary pre-signed file URLs...
        'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wav', 'mp4',
        'mov', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp3', 'm4a',
        'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpga', 'webp', 'wma',
    ],
    'max_upload_time' => 5, // Max duration (in minutes) before an upload is invalidated...
],

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Render On Redirect
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value determines if Livewire will run a component's `render()` method
| after a redirect has been triggered using something like `redirect(...)`
| Setting this to true will render the view once more before redirecting
|
*/

'render_on_redirect' => false,

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Eloquent Model Binding
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Previous versions of Livewire supported binding directly to eloquent model
| properties using wire:model by default. However, this behavior has been
| deemed too "magical" and has therefore been put under a feature flag.
|
*/

'legacy_model_binding' => false,

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Auto-inject Frontend Assets
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, Livewire automatically injects its JavaScript and CSS into the
| <head> and <body> of pages containing Livewire components. By disabling
| this behavior, you need to use @livewireStyles and @livewireScripts.
|
*/

'inject_assets' => true,

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Navigate (SPA mode)
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By adding `wire:navigate` to links in your Livewire application, Livewire
| will prevent the default link handling and instead request those pages
| via AJAX, creating an SPA-like effect. Configure this behavior here.
|
*/

'navigate' => [
    'show_progress_bar' => true,
    'progress_bar_color' => '#2299dd',
],

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTML Morph Markers
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Livewire intelligently "morphs" existing HTML into the newly rendered HTML
| after each update. To make this process more reliable, Livewire injects
| "markers" into the rendered Blade surrounding @if, @class & @foreach.
|
*/

'inject_morph_markers' => true,

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Pagination Theme
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When enabling Livewire's pagination feature by using the `WithPagination`
| trait, Livewire will use Tailwind templates to render pagination views
| on the page. If you want Bootstrap CSS, you can specify: "bootstrap"
|
*/

'pagination_theme' => 'tailwind',
```

];
`

**Printing the image like this**
`<img class="rounded-circle mb-3" src="{{ $new_avatar->temporaryUrl() }}" height="75px" width="75px" alt="preview">`

I've research but couldn't find a solution for this, as it's really really weird.
I've cleared cache, configs, tried to use a different middleware for the livewire uploads but it's still returns the same thing for images that aren't gifs or webp.